# Are Locks AutoCloseable?

Tags: java, resources, java-7, resource-management, locks

Are `Locks` auto-closeable? That is, instead of:

```
Lock someLock = new ReentrantLock();
someLock.lock();
try
{
    // ...
}
finally
{
    someLock.unlock();
}
```

...can I say:

```
try (Lock someLock = new ReentrantLock())
{
    someLock.lock();
    // ...
}
```

...in Java 7?

Comment: you can make a request to have them do that

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No, neither the [`Lock`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) interface (nor the [`ReentrantLock`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) class) implement the `AutoCloseable` interface, which is required for use with the new try-with-resource syntax.

If you wanted to get this to work, you could write a simple wrapper:

```
public class LockWrapper implements AutoCloseable
{
    private final Lock _lock;
    public LockWrapper(Lock l) {
       this._lock = l;
    }

    public void lock() {
        this._lock.lock();
    }

    public void close() {
        this._lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Now you can write code like this:

```
try (LockWrapper someLock = new LockWrapper(new ReentrantLock()))
{
    someLock.lock();
    // ...
}
```

I think you're better off sticking with the old syntax, though. It's safer to have your locking logic fully visible.

Comment: Just to clarify for beginners reading this: In real code you should not create a new lock every time you're locking it, because that removes its function.

Comment: actually, you would want to put the lock call in the constructor, _outside_ of the finally handling.

Comment: The wrapper is not correctly done and is going to cause trouble.  Just ask yourself: in the old way, why the `lock()` statement is put outside the try block.

Comment: @AdrianShum, could you explain what the problem here is?

Comment: @CrazyMan There is no guarantee that `lock()` always success. Which means, `someLock.lock()` could fail with exception, and the above implementation will still call `_lock.unlock()`, which  could cause further problem.  Slightly better solution is to call `_lock.lock()` in LockWrapper's ctor (but there are still edge cases that you need to consider)

Answer (score 63):

I was looking into doing this myself and did something like this:

```
public class CloseableReentrantLock extends ReentrantLock implements AutoCloseable { 
   public CloseableReentrantLock open() { 
      this.lock();
      return this;
   }

   @Override
   public void close() {
      this.unlock();
   }
}
```

and then this as usage for the class:

```
public class MyClass {
   private final CloseableReentrantLock lock = new CloseableReentrantLock();

   public void myMethod() {
      try(CloseableReentrantLock closeableLock = lock.open()) {
         // locked stuff
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm currently doing, and it's making development a breeze. Can't +1 this enough.

Comment: This is the way it should be done. Only, why not call that method `lock()` instead of `open()`?

Comment: Because the override is close and open/close go together better than lock/close (they sounds like they do the same thing).

Comment: For this to work the method needs to return the object, but `lock()` is inherited from `ReentrantLock` and has a void return type. Since `lock()` is not available without breaking the inheritance, `open()` makes sense to go with `close()`.

Comment: I'd consider making the lock itself not AutoCloseable, and instead have `open` return a separate object whose `close` releases the lock. Otherwise, you risk people doing `try(CloseableReentrantLock closeableLock = lock)` without the `open` call.

Comment: This is the best solution, but considering that it's still error-prone, I would probably stick with the traditional (non try-with-resource) approach in a large code-base maintained by multiple developers.

Answer (score 30):

The general-purpose [`ReentrantLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) neither implements nor provides anything that implements the `AutoCloseable` interface necessary for a try-with-resources statement. The concept isn't completely foreign to the Java API though, as [`FileChannel.lock()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#lock()) offers this functionality.

The answers given so far share solutions that have some issues, such as creating an unnecessary object on each lock call, exposing an error-prone API or risk failing after the lock is acquired but before the try-finally is entered.

**Java 7** solution:

```
public interface ResourceLock extends AutoCloseable {

    /**
     * Unlocking doesn't throw any checked exception.
     */
    @Override
    void close();
}

public class CloseableReentrantLock extends ReentrantLock {

    private final ResourceLock unlocker = new ResourceLock() {
        @Override
        public void close() {
            CloseableReentrantLock.this.unlock();
        }
    };

    /**
     * @return an {@link AutoCloseable} once the lock has been acquired.
     */
    public ResourceLock lockAsResource() {
        lock();
        return unlocker;
    }
}
```

Leaner **Java 8** solution using a lambda:

```
public class CloseableReentrantLock extends ReentrantLock {

    /**
     * @return an {@link AutoCloseable} once the lock has been acquired.
     */
    public ResourceLock lockAsResource() {
        lock();
        return this::unlock;
    }
}
```

Demonstration:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CloseableReentrantLock lock = new CloseableReentrantLock();

    try (ResourceLock ignored = lock.lockAsResource()) {
        try (ResourceLock ignored2 = lock.lockAsResource()) {
            System.out.println(lock.getHoldCount());  // 2
        }
    }
    System.out.println(lock.getHoldCount());  // 0
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question about Java 7 and AutoCloseable. Do you mean this to be a separate question?

Comment: Your Java 8 solution is so elegant. Well done! I've posted a related design for `ReadWriteLock` at https://stackoverflow.com/a/48145269/14731

Comment: Best solution, should go to the top!

Answer (score 7):

The `try-with-resource` works well for resources which are created and destroyed when `try-block` is left. It does not work for resources which need to be kept alive. Locks are not created and destroyed upon each usage. They are kept alive and just locked and unlocked. This is why they are not `AutoClosable`.

As others already suggested a wrapper can be used to be created and destroyed by the `try-with-resource` block and to do the locking and unlocking upon creation and destruction.

Answer (score 3):

There's no perfect solution, unless you ignore the allocation costs (most application programmers can, but the lock library writers can not). Then you can use a wrapper

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(access=AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public final class MgLockCloseable implements AutoCloseable {
    public static MgLockCloseable tryLock(Lock lock) {
        return new MgLockCloseable(lock.tryLock() ? lock : null);
    }

    public static MgLockCloseable lock(Lock lock) {
        lock.lock();
        return new MgLockCloseable(lock);
    }

    @Override public void close() {
        if (isLocked()) {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public boolean isLocked() {
        return lock != null;
    }

    @Nullable private final Lock lock;
}
```

in this construct

```
try (LockCloseable lockCloseable = LockCloseable.lock(lock)) {
    doSomethingUnderLock();
} // automatic release
```

See also my [question on CR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/129068/14363).

Answer (score 2):

I think a simple util method which takes a lock and a `Runnable` is better than using the try-with-resource statement with locks.

Like this:

```
public static void locked(Lock lock, Runnable r) {
    lock.lock();

    try {
        r.run();
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
locked(lock, () -> {
    // Do your stuff
});
```

Advantages:

- There is no dummy variable created for the try-with-resource.
- I think it is very clear.

Disadvantage

- A `Runnable` instance is allocated for each calls, something that some of the other solutions avoid. But this is insignificant in almost all cases.
- Only works if you can use Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class AutoCloseableLockWrapper implements AutoCloseable, Lock{
    private final Lock lock;
    public AutoCloseableLockWrapper(Lock l) {
        this.lock = l;
    }
    @Override
    public void lock() {
        this.lock.lock();
    }

    @Override
    public void lockInterruptibly() throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lockInterruptibly();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryLock() {
        return lock.tryLock();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryLock(long time, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
        return lock.tryLock(time,unit);
    }

    @Override
    public void unlock() {
        lock.unlock();
    }

    @Override
    public Condition newCondition() {
        return lock.newCondition();
    }
    @Override
    public void close() {
        this.lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: One clear problem with this implementation is that because you don't force locking on construction, you don't know if the lock needs to be released  in the `close()` function, which imposes more work on the user, they must always create the try-with-resources block with a new `AutoCloseableLockWrapper` and then `lock` before anything can fail or return. Similarly the `tryLock` function is "complicated" as you may not grab the lock, but on exiting the try-with-resources block it will be unlocked...

Comment: How can you use this implementation in a try-with-resource block?  You need a method that performs the lock and returns a Closeable that can be invoked inside the "try()".  Am I missing something?

Comment: @JohnC, Just use AutoCloseableLockWrapper  instead of lock

Comment: Sorry if I am being dense here.. I want a locking functionality that comports with try-with-resource to reduce boilerplate clutter. Can I do that with AutoCloseableLockWrapper? If so, how?  Can you provide sample usage?

Answer (score 1):

Taking [user2357112's shrewd advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965731/are-locks-autocloseable#comment-49435935) into account:

```java
public class CloseableLock {

  private class Unlocker implements AutoCloseable {

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
      lock.unlock();
    }

  }

  private final Lock lock;

  private final Unlocker unlocker = new Unlocker();

  public CloseableLock(Lock lock) {
    this.lock = lock;
  }

  public AutoCloseable lock() {
    this.lock.lock();
    return unlocker;
  }

}
```

Use:

```java
CloseableLock lock = new CloseableLock(new ReentrantLock());

try (AutoCloseable unlocker = lock.lock()) {
    // lock is acquired, automatically released at the end of this block
} catch (Exception it) {
    // deal with it
}
```

Could be interesting to make `CloseableLock` implement `java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock`.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Stephen's answer and user2357112's idea, I have written the following class.

The MyLock class itself is not closeable itself, to force users of the class to call get().

```
public class MyLock  {
    public class Session implements AutoCloseable {
        @Override
        public void close() {
            freeLock();
        }
    }

    private ReentrantLock reentrantLock = new ReentrantLock();

    public Session get() { 
        reentrantLock.lock();
        return new Session();
    }

    private void freeLock() {
        reentrantLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Here is a typical use:

```
MyLock myLock = new MyLock();
try( MyLock.Session session = myLock.get() ) {
    // Lock acquired
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending the Java8 solution of @skoskav to ReentrantReadWriteLock:

```
public interface ResourceLock extends AutoCloseable {
    /**
     * Unlocking doesn't throw any checked exception.
     */
    @Override
    void close();
}
```

```
public class CloseableReentrantRWLock extends ReentrantReadWriteLock {

    /**
     * @return an {@link AutoCloseable} once the ReadLock has been acquired
     */
    public ResourceLock lockRead() {
        this.readLock().lock();
        return () -> this.readLock().unlock();
    }

     /**
     * @return an {@link AutoCloseable} once the WriteLock has been acquired.
     */
    public ResourceLock lockWrite() {
        this.writeLock().lock();
        return () -> this.writeLock().unlock();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that works great and is super efficient at the expense of a `ThreadLocal` lookup per lock request. This solution caches the `AutoCloseable` part/wrapper and reuses it on a per-thread basis.

First we have a wrapper class `ResourceLock` around a normal `Lock` that we will have many instances of. This is the part we want to reuse. The wrapper implements the `Lock` interface so it behaves like a normal `Lock` but one that can be auto closed:

```java
public class ResourceLock implements AutoCloseable, Lock {

    private Lock lock;

    public ResourceLock(Lock lock) {
        this(lock, true);
    }
    
    public ResourceLock(Lock lock, boolean eagerLock) {
        this.lock = lock;
        
        if (eagerLock) {
            lock.lock();
        }
    }

    public void lock() {
        lock.lock();
    }

    public void lockInterruptibly() throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lockInterruptibly();
    }

    public Condition newCondition() {
        return lock.newCondition();
    }

    ResourceLock setLock(Lock lock) {
        this.lock = lock;

        return this;
    }

    public boolean tryLock() {
        return lock.tryLock();
    }

    public boolean tryLock(long time, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
        return lock.tryLock(time, unit);
    }

    public void unlock() {
        lock.unlock();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

In none reusable form you would simply use it like this:

```java
try (ResourceLock ignore = new ResourceLock(rwl.writeLock())) {
    // Resource locked in here
}
```

Or we can add a caching capable wrapper which will let us reuse `ResourceLock` objects per thread.

```java
public class ResourceLockCache {

    private final Lock lock;
    private final Supplier<ResourceLock> cachingStrategy;

    public ResourceLockCache(Lock lock) {
        this.lock = lock;

        final ThreadLocal<ResourceLock> strategy = new ThreadLocal<ResourceLock>() {

            @Override
            protected ResourceLock initialValue() {
                return new ResourceLock();
            }

        };

        this.cachingStrategy = strategy::get;
    }

    public ResourceLockCache(Lock lock, Supplier<ResourceLock> cachingStrategy) {
        this.lock = lock;
        this.cachingStrategy = cachingStrategy;
    }

    public ResourceLock getAsResource() {
        final ResourceLock activeLock = cachingStrategy.get();

        activeLock.setLock(lock);

        return activeLock;
    }

    public ResourceLock getAsResourceAndLock() {
        final ResourceLock activeLock = cachingStrategy.get();

        activeLock.setLock(lock);
        activeLock.lock();

        return activeLock;
    }
}
```

Now we can use reuse each auto-closeable lock:

```java
ResourceLockCache rlc = new ResourceLockCache(new ReentrantLock());
// Or this to change caching strategy to new object per lock
ResourceLockCache rlc2 = new ResourceLockCache(new ReentrantLock(), ResourceLock::new);

try (ResourceLock ignore = rlc.getAsResourceAndLock()) {
    // Resource locked in here
}
```

Also have a `ReadWriteLock` variant for more complex locking needs. It implements the `ReadWriteLock` interface so its more versatile as you can use complex locking strategies such as `tryLock` etc:

```java
public class ResourceRWLockCache implements ReadWriteLock {

    private final ReadWriteLock rwl;
    private final Supplier<ResourceLock> cachingStrategy;

    public ResourceRWLockCache(ReadWriteLock rwl) {
        this.rwl = rwl;

        final ThreadLocal<ResourceLock> strategy = new ThreadLocal<ResourceLock>() {

            @Override
            protected ResourceLock initialValue() {
                return new ResourceLock();
            }

        };

        this.cachingStrategy = strategy::get;
    }

    public ResourceRWLockCache(ReadWriteLock rwl, Supplier<ResourceLock> cachingStrategy) {
        this.rwl = rwl;
        this.cachingStrategy = cachingStrategy;
    }

    public ResourceLock readLock() {
        final ResourceLock activeLock = cachingStrategy.get();

        activeLock.setLock(rwl.readLock());

        return activeLock;
    }

    public ResourceLock readLockAndLock() {
        final ResourceLock activeLock = cachingStrategy.get();

        activeLock.setLock(rwl.readLock());
        activeLock.lock();

        return activeLock;
    }

    public ResourceLock writeLock() {
        final ResourceLock activeLock = cachingStrategy.get();

        activeLock.setLock(rwl.writeLock());

        return activeLock;
    }

    public ResourceLock writeLockAndLock() {
        final ResourceLock activeLock = cachingStrategy.get();

        activeLock.setLock(rwl.writeLock());
        activeLock.lock();

        return activeLock;
    }
}
```

```java
ResourceRWLockCache rwl = new ResourceRWLockCache(new ReentrantReadWriteLock());
// Or this to change caching strategy to new object per lock
ResourceRWLockCache rwl2 = new ResourceRWLockCache(new ReentrantReadWriteLock(), ResourceLock::new);

try (ResourceLock ignore = rwl.writeLockAndLock()) {
    // Resource locked in here
}
```

Hope this solution helps for single and multi lock strategies with re-using the resource release handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Extending [skoskav](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46248923/14731)'s excellent answer to `ReadWriteLock`:

**CloseableLock.java:**

```
public interface CloseableLock extends AutoCloseable
{
    /**
     * Release the lock.
     */
    @Override
    void close();
}
```

**ReadWriteLockAsResource:**

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReadWriteLock;

/**
 * Enables the use of {@code try-with-resources} with {@code ReadWriteLock}.
 */
public final class ReadWriteLockAsResource
{
    private final ReadWriteLock lock;

    /**
     * @param lock a lock
     * @throws NullPointerException if {@code lock} is null
     */
    public ReadWriteLockAsResource(ReadWriteLock lock)
    {
        if (lock == null)
          throw new NullPointerException("lock may not be null");
        this.lock = lock;
    }

    /**
     * Starts a new read-lock.
     *
     * @return the read-lock as a resource
     */
    public CloseableLock readLock()
    {
        Lock readLock = lock.readLock();
        readLock.lock();
        return readLock::unlock;
    }

    /**
     * Starts a new write-lock.
     *
     * @return the write-lock as a resource
     */
    public CloseableLock writeLock()
    {
        Lock writeLock = lock.writeLock();
        writeLock.lock();
        return writeLock::unlock;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new condition.
     *
     * @return a new condition
     */
    public Condition newCondition()
    {
        return lock.writeLock().newCondition();
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
public final class GuideToTheUniverse
{
    private final LockAsResource lock = new LockAsResource(new ReentrantReadWriteLock());
    
    public int answerToLife()
    {
        try (CloseableLock writeLock = lock.writeLock())
        {
            System.out.println("Look ma', no hands!");
            return 42;
        }
    }
}
```