# Why not using a try with lock in java?

Tags: java, locking, deadlock, try-with-resources

I've read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965731/are-locks-autocloseable), and this [blog article](http://www.java7developer.com/blog/?p=256) about *try with resources* locks, as the question popped in my head.
But actually, what I'd rather like would be a *try with lock*, I mean without lock instantiation. It would release us from the verbose

```
lock.lock();
try {
    //Do some synchronized actions throwing Exception 
} finally {
    //unlock even if Exception is thrown
    lock.unlock();
}
```

Would rather look like :

```
? implements Unlockable lock ;
...
try(lock) //implicitly calls lock.lock() 
{
    //Do some synchronized actions throwing Exception 
} //implicitly calls finally{lock.unlock();}
```

So *it would not be a TWR*, but just some boilerplate cleaning.

Do you have any technical reasons to suggest describing *why* this would not be a reasonable idea?

EDIT : to clarify the difference between what I propose and a simple `synchronized(lock){}` block, check this snippet :

```java
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;


public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                ReentrantLock locker =new ReentrantLock();
                Condition condition = locker.newCondition();
                Thread t1 = new Thread("Thread1") {
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                                synchronized(locker){
                                        try {
                                                condition.await();
                                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                                        }
                                        System.out.println("Thread1 finished");
                                }
                        }
                } ;
                Thread t2 = new Thread("Thread2") {
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                                synchronized(locker){
                                        Thread.yield();
                                        condition.signal();
                                        System.out.println("blabla2");
                                }
                        }
                } ;
                t1.start();
                t2.start();
        }

}
```

Execution will result in a `IllegalMonitorStateException`, so lock() and unlock() methods are not implicitly called within `synchronized` block.

Comment: Isn't that what `synchronized` does?

Comment: Note that `lock.lock()` and `synchronized (lock)` are completely different.

Comment: Yeah the user case I was describing in the edit was awaiting for a condition to exit thread from being idle. But apparently it is not a widespread practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you had to deal with a simple case like that, where the pattern of locking/unlocking was limited to a narrow scope like this, you probably don't want to use the more complicated [Lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) class and probably should just be using the `synchronized` keyword, instead. That being said, if for some reason you needed this with the more complicated Lock object, it should be relatively straight-forward to create a wrapper around Lock that implements the [AutoCloseable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) interface to be able to do just that. Example:

```
class AutoUnlock implements AutoCloseable {
  private final Lock lock;

  public static AutoUnlock lock(Lock lock) {
    lock.lock();
    return new AutoUnlock(lock);
  }

  public static AutoUnlock tryLock(Lock lock) {
    if (!lock.tryLock()) {
       throw new LockNotAcquiredException();
    }
    return new AutoUnlock(lock);
  }

  @Override
  public void close() {
    lock.unlock();
  }

  private AutoUnlock(Lock lock) {
    this.lock = lock;
  }
}
```

With a wrapper like the above, you could then do:

```
try (AutoUnlock autoUnlock = AutoUnlock.lock(lock)) {
  // ... do whatever that requires the lock ...
}
```

That being said, the Lock class is typically used for very complicated locking scenarios where this wouldn't be particularly useful. For example, Lock objects may be locked in one function in a class and later unlocked in another function (e.g. locking a row in a database in response to an incoming remote procedure call, and then unlocking that row in response to a later RPC), and thus having such a wrapper or making a Lock AutoCloseable, itself, would be of limited use for the way it is actually used. For more simple scenarios, it's more common to just use an existing concurrent datastructure or use synchronized.

Comment: Right. One purpose of `Lock` is that you can acquire and release it across method boundaries. Since OP doesn't need this with the construct they are suggesting, `synchronized` is enough (obviously it wouldn't lock (obtain monitor) the same way as a `Lock` object).

Comment: I get your point. The main difference is that you have to *instanciate* a new object... so indeed in this case a simple `synchronized will be enough`. But what if you need to `await()` over a condition within your block? Well I'm just a beginner. Thanks for your clear answer!

Comment: For something like calling await(), I'd be more likely to use an existing concurrent queue datastructure in real code. But, if that isn't an option, then yeah, you really do need to use a Lock, then.

Comment: But synchronized can't differentetiate between read and write. That, imo, makes it vastly inferior to the reentrantreadwritelock.

Answer (score 0):

This answer serves to explain the behavior of your edit. The purpose of [`synchronized`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.1) is to lock the monitor of the given object when the thread enters the block (waiting if it isn't available) and releasing it when the thread exits the block.

[`Lock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) is a higher level abstraction.

> `Lock` implementations provide more extensive locking operations than
>   can be obtained using synchronized methods and statements.

You can use it to lock across method boundaries. `synchronized` is not able to do this so a `Lock` cannot be implemented solely with `synchronized` and no implementation I've ever seen uses it. Instead, they use other patterns, like [compare and swap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap). They use this to set a state atomically within a `Lock` object which marks a certain thread as the owner of the lock.

In your code snippet, you try to invoke

```
condition.signal();
```

in a thread which does not own the `Lock` from which the `condition` was created. The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#signal--) states

> An implementation may (and typically does) **require that the current
>   thread hold the lock associated with this `Condition` when this method
>   is called**. Implementations must document this precondition and any
>   actions taken if the lock is not held. Typically, **an exception such as
>   `IllegalMonitorStateException` will be thrown.**

That's what happened here.

Executing

```
synchronized (lock) {}
```

makes the current thread lock (and then release) the monitor on the object referenced by `lock`. Executing

```
lock.lock();
```

makes the current thread set some state within the object referenced by `lock` which identifies it as the owner.

Comment: Thank you Sotirios for your comment. Precisely I wanted to show the `synchronized` block was different from the `lock.lock()` ! We can't agree more on this. I just thought user cases where you need to lock/unlock within your method from object A, but you would also need to use separate lock() and unlock() in different methods of object A were more common.