# How to use lock wrapper for autocloseable?

Tags: java, concurrency, try-with-resources, autocloseable

I have wrote following wrapepr:

```
public class AutoCloseableLockWrapper implements AutoCloseable, Lock{
    private final Lock lock;
    public AutoCloseableLockWrapper(Lock l) {
        this.lock = l;
    }
    @Override
    public void lock() {
        this.lock.lock();
    }

    @Override
    public void lockInterruptibly() throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lockInterruptibly();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryLock() {
        return lock.tryLock();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryLock(long time, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
        return lock.tryLock(time,unit);
    }

    @Override
    public void unlock() {
        lock.unlock();
    }

    @Override
    public Condition newCondition() {
        return lock.newCondition();
    }
    @Override
    public void close() {
        this.lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

In my code I use it like this:

```
public class ReadWriteMap implements Map {

    private HashMap map = new HashMap();
    private ReadWriteLock readWriteLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    private Lock readLock = readWriteLock.readLock();
    private Lock writeLock = readWriteLock.writeLock();

    @Override
    public int size() {
        try (AutoCloseableLockWrapper autoCloseableLockWrapper = new AutoCloseableLockWrapper(readLock)) {
            autoCloseableLockWrapper.lock();
            return map.size();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        try (AutoCloseableLockWrapper autoCloseableLockWrapper = new AutoCloseableLockWrapper(readLock)) {
            autoCloseableLockWrapper.lock();
            return map.isEmpty();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        try (AutoCloseableLockWrapper autoCloseableLockWrapper = new AutoCloseableLockWrapper(readLock)) {
            autoCloseableLockWrapper.lock();
            return map.containsKey(key);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

I don't want to create wrapper in each method.

Is there way to combine single wrapper and try with resources ?

Answer (score 3):

You are over-complicating your design. If your `AutoCloseableLockWrapper` intentionally exposes all operations supported by the underlying `Lock`, there is no point in making it `private` and adding delegation methods for each of `Lock`’s methods. You could simply make the `Lock` reference `public` to allow its use, or leave it off entirely, as the code which creates the wrapper already has a reference to the `Lock`.

All you want to do, is to support a single operation, `unlock`, which should be viewed as `AutoCloseable`.

A Java 8 solution may look like

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;

public interface AutoUnlock extends AutoCloseable {
    public static AutoUnlock lock(Lock lock) {
        lock.lock();
        return lock::unlock;
    }

    @Override
    public void close(); // no checked exceptions
}
```

It can be used like:

```
Lock lock=…
// …
try(AutoUnlock u=AutoUnlock.lock(lock)) {
    // critical code
}
// …
try(AutoUnlock u=AutoUnlock.lock(lock)) {
    // critical code
}
```

If you worry about the instance creation (usually this is *not* an issue), you *can* re-use `AutoCloseable`s:

```
AutoUnlock reusable=lock::unlock;
// …
lock.lock();
try(AutoUnlock u=reusable) {
    // critical code
}
// …
lock.lock();
try(AutoUnlock u=reusable) {
    // critical code
}
```

To me, it looks less clear since the `lock();` and `try` statements are not syntactically coupled and could be separated by accident. But if the lock has a non-local scope, you could solve this by creating a utility method:

```
final Lock lockInstance; // this field name is to prevent confusion with the lock() method
final AutoUnlock reusable;

YourConstructor(Lock lock) {// you may get the Lock as a parameter
    lockInstance=lock; // or create one here, right in the constructor
    reusable=lockInstance::unlock;
}

AutoUnlock lock() {
    lockInstance.lock();
    return reusable;
}
void doSomething() {
    // …
    try(AutoUnlock u=lock()) {
        // critical code
    }
    // …
    try(AutoUnlock u=lock()) {
        // critical code
    }
}
```

I think, it’s not too hard to back-port this logic into Java 7 code, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a factory method that returns a singleton. Nothing is forcing you to use a constructor.

BTW you should not call `lock` inside the try-block. That should have already happened in the "acquire the resource" phase (within the constructor in your current design, inside the factory method in my proposal).

I see that the above note is already posted on the [Q&A page where you contributed your wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31853392/1103872). The page already has very good content; I advise to study it well.

Comment: problem that I cannot write  **AutoCloseableLockWrapper autoCloseableLockWrapper = new AutoCloseableLockWrapper(readLock);
        try (autoCloseableLockWrapper) {
            autoCloseableLockWrapper.lock();
            return map.size();
        }**

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer just creating a new lock (not a wrapper around a lock):

```
public class AutoReentrantLock implements AutoCloseable {
  private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

  public AutoReentrantLock lock() {
    lock.lock();

    return this;
  }

  public void earlyUnlock() {
    lock.unlock();
  }

  @Override
  public void close() {
    if(lock.isHeldByCurrentThread()) {
      lock.unlock();
    }
  }
}
```

Use like this:

```
private AutoReentrantLock consistencyLock = new AutoReentrantLock();

try(AutoReentrantLock lock = consistencyLock.lock()) {
  // other code
}
```

Or a more complicated use case, where you unlock halfway:

```
private AutoReentrantLock consistencyLock = new AutoReentrantLock();

try(AutoReentrantLock lock = consistencyLock.lock()) {
  // Place code here that gathers information (while under lock)        
  // but may exit early or throw exceptions

  lock.earlyUnlock();

  // ... followed by code that is slow that acts upon above gathered information.
}
```